# move to forward or backward - Python - ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am intended to create a GUI FTP application by using Python and PyGTK.
So I have chosen ftplib.

Requirement is I want to create two buttons. Butoon 1 Forward and Button 2 Backward. When I click backward then it have to move to last directory. If I assume my object and function as

ftp.cwd() then What I have to pass as an argument  i.e ftp.cwd(something that send to backward).

Help me Please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cwd()` is the correct method to change the remote (on ftp server) directory.

> something that send to backward

To implement forward/backward buttons, you need a list of previously visited directories. You could use `collections.deque()` that has [`.rotate()` method that allows to move forwards and backwards in the history list.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate)

You could use `maxlen` parameter to limit the history size. `.append()` adds a new item to the history. Each item may be a simple string representing the remote path. You can pass these strings to `.cwd()` method to change the directory.

Comment: so you mean no need to deal with cwd() ?

Comment: @Raja: what do you mean?

Comment: I think I understand . I have to pass your answer as argument to cwd right ?